# When using ngRepeat track by dont update DOM on move

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

For my particular application, I want to be able to use an ng-repeat on a custom directive and track by a property of the object.

The problem I'm running into is that I am intentionally not wanting my custom directive to be rendered in the DOM where it is written. I want to take the template (including the directive element) and some variables that exist in it's parent scope and have them compiled and appended inside some markup that is being generated by a 3rd party library.

This way I can write something like:

```
<my-directive ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id"
              ng-click="someCtrl.doSomethingWithAService();">
</my-directive>
```

And have this code appended elsewhere where it functions the same way.

The collection that is being repeated over can change frequently, but I don't want to recreate the appended content, and want to be able to remove it when the scope of each directive instance is destroyed.

I've tried as many approaches as I can think of, and some have been "good enough". The main issue I'm running into now is that when the collection is updated, the tracked items that didn't change end up being added to the DOM where the markup was originally written.

So on first load, everything works. Update collection: directive logic doesn't run again and the element is appended back to where the ng-repeat was.

Any ideas?

Edit:

```
window.angular.module('my.module')
    .directive('myDirective', ['myService',
        function (myService) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: true,
                replace: true,
                templateUrl: '/path/to/template.tpl.html',
                compile: function (tElement, tAttributes) {
                    tElement.removeAttr('ng-repeat');
                    return {
                        post: function (scope, iElement, iAttributes, controller, transcludeFn) {
                            iElement.remove();
                            var item = myService.addItem(scope, iElement[0].outerHTML);
                            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                            // remove item added in service
                            });
                        }
                    };
                }
            };
        }]);
```

The directive essentially looks like this.

Service:

```
window.angular.module('my.module')
    .factory('myService', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        function addItem(scope, template) {
            var element = angular.element(document.querySelector('some-selector'));
            element.html('').append($compile(template)(scope));
        }
        return {
            addItem: addItem
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Show your code of directive `my-directive`.